# FN key seems stuck on MacBook Air. Can't use function keys as normal

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

When I press the function keys they act like the fn key is pressed. For example f11 usually lowers the volume, but when fn is pressed at the same time it shows the keyboard - and that's what happening now whether fn is pressed or not. This results in that I can't for example lower my volume (f11), or play music (f8).

I've tried:

- Restarting my computer
- Changing "Use F1, F2, etc as normal function keys" (System preferences > Keyboard) on and off
- Spamming the fn key trying to feel if something is physically stuck making it being pressed down
- Booting in safe mode

### TL;DR

#### Expected behaviour

When pressing f11 the volume should step down

#### Actual behaviour

The desktop is shown (windows moves aside)

Mojave: 10.14.6

Comment: Also, there are three places to check, Sys Pref -> Mission Control, SysPref -> Keyboard -> shortcuts, and the usual you did syspref -> keyboard -> keyboard, F1F2 as normal keys. It should be unchecked.

Comment: @ankii yes, thank you, that was a typo. I checked the three places you said but couldn't find anything there

Comment: Does this issue still exist in safe mode? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262

Comment: @drivec yes it does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By updating to Catalina the problem was fixed! Although I don't belive it was solved by the update itself but rather some sort of reset or reboot that occured while updating.